# Java thread.sleep standard curiosity

Tags: java

Just for curiosity, why when working with java threads it is like a standard to use Thread.sleep(100) ? 
Why not another value instead of 100?

Comment: Who cares? Let it sleep however long you want it to sleep.

Comment: I am curious... Where do you see that lines of code?

Comment: You can use any number you like. The `100` is miliseconds. It's not a standard or anything. Just 1/10 of a second, which is easy to comprehend.

Comment: This is not a standard, maybe you think this is because you checked the code of some slow fps games.

Comment: I know that there is not a standard. While updating UI from javaFx I saw it a lot. Just a curious question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no technical reason for it.
It is a nice round number, so it is aesthetically pleasing. It is also a very simple fraction of a second (1/10).

Answer (score 2):

There is no such standard. You've just seen code where `sleep(100);` is used a lot and you assumed that it is a standard.